# Inspecting Lucene.NET index with Luke want to replicate NHibernate.Search view

Tags: c#, nhibernate, lucene.net, luke

I am trying to put together an index using terms, which I specify as a comma separated list. I want to replicate the display in Luke as seen here:

http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/05/03/nhibernate-search-again.aspx

But my index value just shows as a single field with the comma separate list value. For example:

Tags    term,anotherterm

When I search my index, it will return results if I search with "term" but will not return anything if I search with "anotherterm"

I thought the indexing process would break the comma separate list apart into separate values but this does not seem to be the case.

Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was answered as part of this question:

[Lucene.NET search index approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549155/lucene-net-search-index-approach/2581447#2581447)

Answer (score 0):

The collection to index is ISet<T> and I suspect that T is a type with [Indexed] attribute and has a property Name marked with [Field] attribute.